# Wine application in system tray

Tags: 12.04, unity, wine, system-tray

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity. Somehow I managed to minimize one Wine application into system tray from where it cannot be restored - it does not respond neither to double-click nor to right-click nor to anything else. So I killed it from the terminal. However, whenever I start the application now it goes directly to the system tray again. Even if I make Wine to emulate Windows desktop in a window, the application starts in the Windows system tray in that window.

Where or how can I configure start-up options of Wine applications under Unity and unset their starting minimized to the system tray? Or, for that matter, where can I configure *any* application's start-up options regarding the application's initial window state?

Thx.

Comment: Not an answer or anything, but I have noticed that in GNOME, some Wine applications can't be brought into focus. That might have something to do with it.